# Jump to Documentation for a function/class in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

In Eclipse and Xcode it is possible to jump directly to the documentation for a function/class from the editor. Does Visual Studio provide this functionality?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

[Visual Studio Default Settings Shortcut Keys (via the Internet Archive Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130629014319/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xte2hh6a(VS.71).aspx)

[Integrated Help shortcut keys (via the Internet Archive Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130629014319/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xte2hh6a(VS.71).aspx#vxurfvisualstudio70defaultshortcutkeysintegratedhelpanchor1)

[Default keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio)

[Default keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio - Help section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#bkmk_help)

Btw. with <kbd>F12</kbd> you can go to the declaration of selected item in code.

Comment: I did Google, its just that F1 wasn't working before (I think I was mouse overing rather than clicking)

Comment: I find often (and hilariously) that the first result of my Google query is a StackOverflow question where the first answer includes the "try google" phrase. Amusing.

Comment: @Vi3GameHkr [recursion <3](https://www.google.com/search?q=Jump%20to%20Documentation%20for%20a%20function/class%20in%20Visual%20Studio)

Comment: @Mike - This opens up the documentation in a browser. Is there a way to see the documentation in visual studio itself ? (like it is in eclipse or inteliij idea)

Answer (score 2):

Ah, try hitting F1 when your cursor is over a function or class.  That should initiate a search in the MSDN documentation.  Give that a shot!

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of Eclipse. But in visual studio, you can do the documentation within the studio. You can document the class or a method by putting the details in the comment section (with each line starting with a '///') like the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds one item at a time to the cart
/// </summary>
/// <param name="itemToBuy">Selected item from the catalog</param>
/// <param name="qnty">Quantity bought</param>
public void AddItem(item itemToBuy, int qnty, double price, bool isImported)
```

This is for doing documentation for your own code.

To get help, or see documentation, pressing F1 or Ctrl+F1 while keeping the cursor on top of the item takes you to the MSDN.

Comment: Ctrl+F1 gives me the following message: "Waiting for second key of chord".